# Pyplot animation inserts large padding

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

```py
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
fig.add_subplot(3, 2, (3, 4))
```

draws as expected

[image]

but the animation

```py
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class Animation(animation.TimedAnimation):
    def __init__(self):
        fig = plt.figure()
        fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
        fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
        fig.add_subplot(3, 2, (3, 4))
        animation.TimedAnimation.__init__(self, fig, blit=True)

    def _draw_frame(self, frame_idx): pass

    def new_frame_seq(self): return iter(range(2))

ani = Animation()
ani.save('test.mp4')
```

inserts much padding

[image]

This can be remedied via `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=-.5, top=1)` (note negative `bottom`), but it changes the originally intended proportions. Additionally, `plt.show()` at end of animation draws same as direct plot (without `subplots_adjust`), but it's only the last frame.

How to make `animation` pad same as direct plot, or otherwise remove this padding? `matplotlib 3.4.3`, Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Can reduce height via `figsize`, calibrating back and forth with `top` and `bottom`. But this shouldn't be needed.